# How to speed up nested for loops python

Tags: python

I have the following code that I am trying to speed up:

```
for alpha in range(-N,N+1):
    for beta in range(-N,N+1):
        I1 = (alpha+N)+(beta+N)*(2*N+1)
        for gamma in range(-N,N+1):
            for delta in range(-N,N+1):
                if alpha!=gamma or beta!=delta:
                   J1 = (gamma+N)+(delta+N)*(2*N+1)
                   temp1 = 0;
                   for nn in range(0,numphases-1):
                       R = pi*(sqrt((a[nn+1]*(alpha-gamma)/a[0])**2+((b[nn+1]*(beta-delta)/b[0])**2)))
                      temp1 += (f[nn+1,mm]-f[nn,mm])*(pi/2)*((a[nn+1]*b[nn+1]))*(fp.besselj(1,R[0,0]))/R[0,0]
                   Lambda[I1,J1,mm] = temp1[0,0]
```

for values of N equals > 1.

I've looked at many examples of parallelizing it and vectorizing it but I'm still not sure what I can do to speed it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out [the code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Also, I have no clue what your code does.  It's difficult to read.

Comment: are you on python2.x or python3.x?  On python2.x, you could use `xrange` and get some speedups there.  Otherwise, you'll probably want to move to something like `numpy`.

Comment: Maybe you could describe what that O(n**5) algorithm (!) is supposed to be doing instead.

Comment: The easiest way will be to put every loop definition into a function and then execute it with multiprocessing.Process. It's simple, it's low-level and it works.

Comment: Please tell us what the code is supposed to do. I can't possibly imagine that a quintuple-nested loop is an optimal structure for your algorithm.

Comment: Q: "How to speed up nested for loops python?" A: Don't have so many. Q: How do I get help? A: Try the method in [whathaveyoutried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) for constructive advice.

Comment: This is a segment of the my code for an electromagnetic simulation, in this part I'm trying to solve the following equation in the code above: Summation from 2 to numphases of (f_k-f_{k-1})g_k where g_k = (pi/2)(a_1(k)a_2(k)J(R_k))/R_k where J is the bessel function and R_k=pi((sqrt(a[nn+1]*(alpha-gamma)/a[0])**2+((b[nn+1]*(beta-delta)/b[0])**2))
So I don't see any way for me to reduce the number of for loops

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 and xrange does seem to make a slight difference but nothing significant..
I've been able to vectorize other parts of my code but I'm not sure how to start vectorizing this because of the innermost loop using the bessel command. I am slo using numpy but I'm rather new to numpy so there's likely something I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this kind of loops is by using numpy and multi dimensional arrays and try to vectorize the calculation. Each loop corresponds to another dimension of a numpy array. You would start with the innermost loop and you could write it something like:

```
Lambda[I1,J1,mm] = sum(f[1:,mm]-[f[0:-1,mm]*pi/2+a[1:]*b[1:]*fp.besselj(1,R)/R
```

You would then move outwards eac time adding another dimension. But this is very trickery, and might not always work out. In this case, e.g. I couldn't figure out how to stuff R both into the Bessel function and into the nominator.

An easier approach is just to rewrite the calculation, at the very least the inner loops in C or C++ either natively or by various binding libraries, and then just call the routine from Python.

Comment: Cython worked, thanks!